# AlarmManager that repeat at specific time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

With AlarmManager you can set an alarm at specific time, and repeat it at specified interval of time

```
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 4*60*60*1000, alarmIntent);
```

In the example the alarm is repeating every 4 hours, but is it possible to set an alarm that trigger at specific time and repeat at specific times? For example: I want to set an alarm that start a service at 9:00  and repeat it at 11:30, 17:30 and 20:00. The service must start all days approximately at these hours.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not this way?

```
long now     = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
long time24h = 24*60*60*1000;
long timeAt09_00 = ...; // calculate from now...
long timeAt11_30 = ...; // calculate from now...

alarmMgr1.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now ,        time24h, alarmIntent);
alarmMgr2.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeAt09_00, time24h, alarmIntent);
alarmMgr3.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeAt11_30, time24h, alarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create 4 alarms which starts at 9:00, 11:30, 17:30 and 20:00 with `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` and set repeating interval to be 24 hours (=24*60*60*1000)

Comment: @dit and Carnal thanks for the fast responses. When both give me this solutions, I supose that is because is not possible to do it with only one alarm, isn't it?

Comment: as far as I know, it is not possible. You can only have a constant repeat interval.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` method.

See [AlarmManager Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123543/alarmmanager-repeat) for an example.

Here is the Android documentation also regarding [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), with explanation and sample code.